# Bug in Notepad++ / BOOST or bug in my regular expression?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file which is structured like this:

```
Line
foo Änderbar: PM baz
Line

Line
foo Änderbar: OM baz
Line

Line
foo Änderbar: ++ baz
Line

Line
foo Änderbar: -- baz
Line
```

So the file consists of "blocks" which are separated by a newline (I have converted the file to Unix line endings). Each block can have an arbitrary number of lines. Each line of a block contains at least one character which is not a newline, and is finished by a newline character. The lines which separate the blocks consist of exactly one newline character.

In each block, there is exactly one line in the following format:

- at least one character which is not newline, followed by
- the literal string `'Änderbar: '`, followed by
- exactly one of the literal strings `'++'`, `'--'`, `'OM'`, `'PM'`, followed by
- at least one character which is not newline, followed by
- the line-terminating newline character

There is always at least one other non-empty line in the same block above this special line and one other non-empty line below this special line.

I need an effective method to find (and thereby select) all blocks where the literal after `Änderbar:` is `--` (find / select one block after another, each one after hitting `Find Next` again, i.e. not selecting all of those blocks at the same time).

Normally, I have fun solving such problems with Notepad++. However, in that case, it seems that I either get more and more stupid as I get older, or that there is a bug in Notepad++'s regex handling engine.

Notepad++ uses BOOST (and supports PCRE expressions via BOOST). Since this is in wide use, I consider that problem important enough to post it here, just in case that BOOST really is the reason for the misbehavior.

Having said this: I loaded that file into Notepad++, fired up the Search and Replace dialog, ticked `. matches newline`, ticked `Regular Expression` and entered the following regex in the `Find What:` textbox:

```
\n([^\n]+\n)+[^\n]+(Änderbar\:\ --[^\n]+\n)([^\n]+\n)+
```

I was quite surprised that this made Notepad++ behave weirdly: When the cursor was placed in the empty line immediately before a block with `Änderbar: --`, hitting `Find Next` found / selected that block as expected. But when the cursor was at another place, hitting `Find Next` made Notepad++ find / select *the whole rest of the file*, i.e. all blocks below the cursor position.

I then have tested if it would find the blocks having `++` after `Änderbar:`, i.e. I changed my regex to

```
\n([^\n]+\n)+[^\n]+(Änderbar\:\ \+\+[^\n]+\n)([^\n]+\n)+
```

Guess what: This was working reliably in each situation. The same is true for the last both:

```
\n([^\n]+\n)+[^\n]+(Änderbar\:\ PM[^\n]+\n)([^\n]+\n)+
\n([^\n]+\n)+[^\n]+(Änderbar\:\ OM[^\n]+\n)([^\n]+\n)+
```

So Notepad++ / PCRE seems to have a problem with the correct interpretation of `-` under certain circumstances, or I have a subtle bug in my regex which only triggers when I am searching for `--` (instead of `++`, `OM` or `PM`) at the respective place.

Please note that I already have tried to leave away the `\` in front of the space character (which actually could only make the situation worse, but I've tried just in case) and that I also have tried to use `\-\-` instead of `--` (although the latter should be fine). That did not alter the (mis-)behavior in any way.

So what is the problem here? Is there a bug in my regex, or is there a bug in Notepad++?

**UPDATE**

I have stripped down the actual file in question and have uploaded it to https://pastebin.com/w62E57U5. To reproduce the problem, please do the following:

- Download the file from the link above and save it somewhere on your HDD (do not copy the text directly into Notepad++).
- Load the file into Notepad++. The cursor now is in the topmost line, and nothing is selected.
- **This is essential:** Click Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix (LF).
- Verify that the cursor is still in the topmost line (which is empty) and that nothing is selected.
- Open the Find dialog and choose the settings and enter the search string as described above.
- Click "Find Next".
- Note that now the complete text is found / selected.
- Keeping the Find window open, delete the third line of the file (it reads "Funktionspaket(e): ML"). Do not just empty that line, but really delete it so that no empty line remains between the line before and the line after.
- Again, place the cursor in the topmost line (which is still empty) and make sure nothing is selected.
- Click "Find Next".
- Note that the regular expression now works as expected.

Obviously, somebody is trying to make a fool of me, right?

Comment: Notepad++ has a [Github repository](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus).  Why don't you [raise an issue?](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues)

Comment: Because I'd like to know first if it is my own fault ...

Comment: You might want to try testing your regex at https://regex101.com/

Comment: Notepad++ uses [BOOST regex](https://www.boost.org/), not PCRE.

Comment: It works pretty fine for me with your provided example.

Comment: With `. matches newline` UNticked, you could simplify your regex: `\R(?:.+\R)+.+(Änderbar: --.+\R)(?:.+\R)+` that doesn't requier to change tthe line ending. `\R` stands for any kind of linebreak.

Comment: Could you show the real content of the file or, at least, 2 or 3 blocks?

Comment: @Toto OK, you are right and the info I got from another website was wrong. Notepad++ uses BOOST (and supports PCRE using it, but not use PCRE libraries as such). I'll correct that part of my question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've tried at regex101.com; it works as expected there (after having increased the timeout to 50 seconds). Thanks for the tip.

Comment: For what it's worth, `\n((?:\n.+)*Änderbar\: \-\-.*(?:\n.+)*)` is two orders of magnitude faster than what you're using right now - I think you've got a backtracking issue somewhere. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sy1J0c/2/)

Comment: I've just made some tests with your file, `^(?:(?!\R\R)(?!Änderbar: ).)+?Änderbar: --(?:(?!\R\R).)*` seems working. What do you think? (`. matches newline` must be checked)

Comment: @Toto Some remarks: 1) Your regex seems to work - thank you very much! 2) But the actual question still is why my regex does not work. 3) I have updated my question after having noticed that there was no problem in the part of the file I had uploaded the first time. I have now uploaded another part of the file where the problem can be reproduced - please see my update of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key is: you need to begin your regex with `^` (beginning of line).

Your original regex becomes:

```
^\n([^\n]+\n)+[^\n]+(Änderbar\:\ --[^\n]+\n)([^\n]+\n)+
```

But you can simplify it with:

```
^\R(?:.+\R)+.+Änderbar: --.+\R(?:.+(?:\R|\z))+
```

#### Note: tick `. matches newline`

Where:

- `\R` matches any kind of linebreak, no needs to change the EOL.
- `\z` matches the end of file, if you don't use it, you can't match the last line of the file if there're no linebreak.
- `(?:...)` is a non capture group, much more efficient (if you don't need to capture, of course)

Both works fine with your 2 sample files.

Comment: The version with the `^` seems to work (and, by the way, `^` replaced by an additional `\n` works as well). But this does still not explain Notepad++'s weird behavior. My original search pattern definitely does not match the whole file. Plus, it behaves differently when deleting one line (see my update) or when using one of `++, OM, PM` instead of `--`. So I'll probably rise an issue for Notepad++. Nevertheless, giving you the answer and upvoting because you were taking the time and you answer worked.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug. You're just forgetting something very important - with Windows line endings, your lines have a `\r` before the `\n`, so the `\n([^\n]+\n)+` part of your RegEx will also match your blank lines which is why clicking "Find Next" matches everything from the cursor position instead of from the start of the block.

Go to Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix (LF) and you'll see that it works now. If you want to support Windows *and* Unix line endings you'll have to change every `[^\n]` to `[^\r\n]` and every `\n` to `\r?\n`.

Comment: I've already done that as described in my question ("I have converted the file to Unix line endings") :-) However, +1 for taking the time and because I probably should have stated this more prominently.